# How can I make a custom widget in the lxpanel

Tags: server, openbox, lxpanel

I am using Openbox as my window manager, and Ubuntu Server 16.04 as the base system.

I use lxpanel as my navigation bar. I need to make a custom widget to show the filesystem information in the taskbar.

How can I make that custom widget for the lxpanel?

Answer (score 1):

The official reference for how to develop lxpanel plugins is at https://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXPanel

Basically, you should be able to do most of what you want by customizing your config file.